# Smallipop jquery plugin - how to reduce triangle size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to reduce the size of the triangle shape on the tooltip for the smallipop plugin ?
[Smallipop website.](http://projects.sebastianhelzle.net/jquery.smallipop/index.html)

[image]

I'd like the triangle to be about 2px less width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override their classes.

```
.smallipop-instance:after
```

and

```
.smallipop-instance:before
```

There are probably multiple ones to handle different screen sizes and placement of the triangle. Each one has some CSS styles that correspond to the triangle being on top, bottom, left or right. The important styles are:

```
top: -24px;
bottom: -20px;
margin-left: -10px;
border: 10px solid transparent;
```

Not those specific values but those CSS properties. I just grabbed those examples from their CSS. To change the size of the triangle you will need to adjust the `border` pixel size. A lower value means a smaller triangle.

Changing that will cause the triangle to not be centered and directly against the tooltip any longer. Depending on where the triangle is: top, left, right or bottom you will need to adjust the correct class and change its `top` or `bottom` value and its `margin-left` value to compensate for the size change.

There are also some classes

```
.smallipop-left:after
.smallipop-right:after
.smallipop-bottom:after
```

That look like they depending on the placement of the tooltip and triangle will override the margins, top, left, right or bottom values.

I hope that helps you start understanding and making the changes you need!

Comment: okay, thanks.  That would be cool if they exposed an option for it, but this will work for now.

Comment: @looshi yea I went through their options but didn't see anything so overriding CSS seems like only option.